# jpeg outside of div margin?

Tags: html, margins

hello   If a large image is to be used for a web page that is very wide such as this >

http://oi58.tinypic.com/14l2fx3.jpg

As you can see above^ The centre of this image is the text and the star spreads out.

I wonder, is it possible to auto centre this super wide image in a browser; so that when the image is displayed on a 4:3 screen or zoomed in, it auto crops?

I presume this would require the image to go outside the screen/margins when zoomed in or on a 4:3 so that the text is still centred?

The reason I ask is to avoid having to use a cropped image in the first place and seeing this (below)when zoomed out or on a wide screen.

http://oi60.tinypic.com/55jsyw.jpg

I'm rather new to html and css.

thank you for any help you may offer  : )

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="background-image:url('Image.jpg');">
```

Answer (score 0):

use `margin:0 auto` for the image in the css

```
height:500px;
background-image:url('14l2fx3.jpg');
margin:0 auto;
```